# ECS service start tasks by itself

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I've learn through the tutorial [here](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-application-for-long-running-process-fargate-lambda/) and have noticed that the service or ECS generally creates and executes tasks all the time. I have used this command to start a task:

```
aws --region us-east-1 ecs run-task --task-definition ffmpeg-thumb-task-definition
```

Actually, after a single execution, the task should not be restarted, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, once execution completed task will not start again, this is the main difference between task and services.

In short, the life of task is the life of container CMD or entrypoint. but no matter how you start the task either from service or manually it passes through the lifecycle.

[image]

> When a task is started, either manually or as part of a service, it
>   can pass through several states before it finishes on its own or is
>   stopped manually. Some tasks are meant to run as batch jobs that
>   naturally progress through from PENDING to RUNNING to STOPPED. Other
>   tasks, which can be part of a service, are meant to continue running
>   indefinitely, or to be scaled up and down as needed.

[task-lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-lifecycle.html)

The task is helpful for short term job execution, where you do not need the container up and running every time, but you just need the container to perform the job and then terminate the task or container.

[ecs_services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_services.html)